# Pixate apply border to single side

Tags: ios, pixate

Is there a way to set only the top border for an element through Pixate? I don't see it in the docs.

I've tried both of these, but they apply the border to all four sides:

```
#footer {
    border-top:5px solid #FF0000;
}
#footer {
    border:5px solid #FF0000;
    border-width:5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** I am talking about [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/) here, NOT browser CSS!

Comment: Whoever downvoted obviously didn't take the time to read the question... P.I.X.A.T.E. Also, someone with 12k rep who can't figure out a CSS border? Unlikely.

Comment: I'll vote you back up :-) I don't now the answer, though I know what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply a border to a single side, no.

But there is a workaround:

```
#footer {
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px solid #FF0000;
}
```

That should create the same effect. Good luck. :)